# Reading parameter field values

Tags: android

This is possibly the noobiest of noob questions, but I can't find the answer anywhere - maybe because I have my terminology wrong, maybe because it's not possible.

What I'm trying to do is determine whether a chronometer widget in Android is running, but the more general question is:

**How do I read the field values that I can see in the IDE/debugger programatically?**

For example, if I set a breakpoint after my chronometer is started, in the variables list (or when evaluating the chronometer), I can see a load of useful stuff all beginning with the letter 'm'. For example, mVisible, mRunning, mStarted, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to access them.

I'd like to know if this is possible in both Java and Kotlin, please. I've attached a screengrab of what I'm talking about :)

Thanks,
Iain

[image: What I'm trying to say]

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked this out. I've declared an extension function:

```
fun Chronometer.isRunning(): Boolean {
    val f = this::class.java.getDeclaredField("mRunning")
    f.isAccessible=true               // make it readable
    return f.get(this) as Boolean
}
```

I can then read the value of mRunning with myChronometer.isRunning()

Suggestions for improvements are welcome. :)